# how to log messages to a file when running multiple processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am learning about logging when running multiple process.

Below is how I normally log things when running a single process.

```py
import logging

log_format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(messsage)s'
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel('Debug')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('C:/my_directory/logs/file_name.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter(log_format)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# to stop duplication
if not len(logger.handlers):
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

So after my code has run I can go to C:/my_directory/logs/file_name.log & check what I need to.

With multiple processes I understand its not so simple. I have read this [great article](https://superfastpython.com/multiprocessing-logging-in-python/#Example_Using_QueueHandler_and_a_Logging_Process). I have copied the example code below. What I don't understand is how to output the logged messages to a file like above so that I can read it after the code has finished?

```py
from random import random
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import current_process
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
from logging.handlers import QueueHandler
import logging

# executed in a process that performs logging
def logger_process(queue):
    # create a logger
    logger = logging.getLogger('app')
    # configure a stream handler
    logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    # log all messages, debug and up
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # run forever
    while True:
        # consume a log message, block until one arrives
        message = queue.get()
        # check for shutdown
        if message is None:
            break
        # log the message
        logger.handle(message)

 # task to be executed in child processes
 def task(queue):
    # create a logger
    logger = logging.getLogger('app')
    # add a handler that uses the shared queue
    logger.addHandler(QueueHandler(queue))
    # log all messages, debug and up
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # get the current process
    process = current_process()
    # report initial message   
    logger.info(f'Child {process.name} starting.')
    # simulate doing work
    for i in range(5):
        # report a message
        logger.debug(f'Child {process.name} step {i}.')
        # block
       sleep(random())
    # report final message
    logger.info(f'Child {process.name} done.')

 # protect the entry point
 if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create the shared queue
    queue = Queue()
    # create a logger
    logger = logging.getLogger('app')
    # add a handler that uses the shared queue
    logger.addHandler(QueueHandler(queue))
    # log all messages, debug and up
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # start the logger process
    logger_p = Process(target=logger_process, args=(queue,))
    logger_p.start()
    # report initial message
    logger.info('Main process started.')
    # configure child processes
    processes = [Process(target=task, args=(queue,)) for i in range(5)]
    # start child processes
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
     # wait for child processes to finish
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
    # report final message
    logger.info('Main process done.')
    # shutdown the queue correctly
    queue.put(None)
```

**Update**

I added the below code in the logger_process function just before the While True: loop. However when I look in the file, there is nothing there. I'm not seeing any output, not sure what I'm missing?

```
# add file handler
log_format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(messsage)s'
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('C:/my_directory/logs/file_name.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter(log_format)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

Comment: All the log entries are being sent over the Queue to the "logger_process" where you currently only have a stream handler. You need to add a file handler to the logger in your logger_process in a similar way to how you did in the single process version.

Comment: @Aaron thanks just put the link in. Had problems posting the question so copied it over, must have done something to the link. Just testing what you said in your other comment

Comment: you have a typo... You're probably running in an IDE where print statements from child processes are not properly collected. Otherwise you would have seen the error messages from each log message: "KeyError: 'messsage'" (3 "s") from `log_format`

Comment: @Aaron thanks very much. If you post an answer happy to mark it as correct